# How does the Liberation Domain cleric's condition-suppressing aura from Freedom's Call work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, conditions, domains, aura

I have been reading the cleric domains, and have a question about an ability from the [Liberation Domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/liberation-domain).

The ability I am unsure about is:

> *Freedom's Call (Su):* At 8th level, you can emit a 30-foot aura of freedom for a number of rounds per day equal to your cleric level. Allies within this aura are not affected by the confused, grappled, frightened, panicked, paralyzed, pinned, or shaken conditions. This aura only suppresses these effects, and they return once a creature leaves the aura or when the aura ends, if applicable. These rounds do not need to be consecutive.

- What does it mean that it only suppresses the effect?
- What does this mean to someone who is grappled? Does it mean that the
  grappled condition is suppressed so they can freely move and attack,
  but if the effect disappears then they are grappled again?
- Is this automatic or do rolls need to be made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an effect is suppressed, it means it no longer has any effect. This can happen in various ways (like an anti-magic field). The duration of the suppressed effect is usually not changed and if, when the suppressor ends, the effect is still present then its effects return.

So, a character has the shaken condition. A cleric uses Freedom's Call. As long as the Call is active (and the character in the radius), the character does not take any of the penalties described in that [condition's entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Shaken)

Likewise, 'Grappled' is a [condition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled):

> A grappled creature is restrained by a creature, trap, or effect. Grappled creatures cannot move and take a –4 penalty to Dexterity. A grappled creature takes a –2 penalty on all attack rolls and combat maneuver checks, except those made to grapple or escape a grapple. In addition, grappled creatures can take no action that requires two hands to perform. A grappled character who attempts to cast a spell or use a spell-like ability must make a concentration check (DC 10 + grappler's CMB + spell level), or lose the spell. Grappled creatures cannot make attacks of opportunity.
>
> A grappled creature cannot use Stealth to hide from the creature grappling it, even if a special ability, such as hide in plain sight, would normally allow it to do so. If a grappled creature becomes invisible, through a spell or other ability, it gains a +2 circumstance bonus on its CMD to avoid being grappled, but receives no other benefit.
>
> Casting Spells while Grappled/Grappling: The only spells which can be cast while grappling or pinned are those without somatic components and whose material components (if any) you have in hand. Even so, you must make a concentration check (DC 10 + the grappler's CMB + the level of the spell you're casting) or lose the spell.

While under the effect of the Call, a character would be able to move and act normally. While it is not stated, I would rule that if a grappled character moved away from its grappler, it would no longer be grappled. Likewise, if a character did NOT move before the Call ended, it would still be grappled just as is was before.

This would all be automatic with no rolls being made (beyond attacks of opportunity and actions and whatnot).

Answer (score 4):

#### Suppressed means that the effect being suppressed does not affect your character until the supressing effect lasts.

Example:
You become affected by a [Red Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-red/red-dragon-juvenile/longtooth)'s [aura of fear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Frightful-Presence-Ex-), which means you will likely become shaken for 5d6 rounds.

Then, you activate your *Freedom's Call*, which will last for 8 rounds.

At the end of those 8 rounds, you become shaken again. Because the effect was only suppressed, not removed or countered in some way.

As for the **grapple**, that will depend on how they were grappled.

First we must see the difference between the [Grapple Condition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) and the [Grapple Combat Maneuver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple).

Certain effects, like the combat maneuver, will require the grappler to maintain the grapple or the condition will end to both participants, if the grappler cannot maintain it, the grapple ends.

While other effects, like a net, will apply the grapple effect was suppressed, but the net was not removed, so at the end of the *Freedom's Call*, the character will be grappled again.

Likewise, a [Web Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web) effect would also resume the grapple conditions on all creatures once the suppressing effect is over.